# Angular 6, use of ' _ ' as a parameter

Tags: angular

I am checking out codes online for  and I came across a code with a line that looks like `hasChild = (_: number, node: ExampleFlatNode) => node.expandable;`

I want to understand what does `_: number` mean? More specifically, what is the underscore used for?

Comment: It is a parameter name that is passed into the declared arrow function. You can name `_` whatever you want, this author just happened to prefer `_` instead of `argNumber` or anything else.

Comment: Just a name of that parameter, nothing special

Comment: It is preferred to use `_`, when the variable should be declared but not used in the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is a parameter name that is passed into the declared arrow function. You can name `_` whatever you want, this author just happened to prefer `_` instead of `argNumber` or anything else.